# Biblatex raggedright bibliography with polyglossia hebrew

Tags: biblatex, horizontal-alignment, hebrew

The `xelatex` with `biblatex` can generate `raggedright` bibliography by means of

```
\raggedright\printbibliography
```

but adding `hebrew` to `polyglossia`:

```
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
```

disables this functionality, i.e. the Bibliography is justify to the margins and hyphenation works.

How to switch off the hyphenation in the Bibliography with the `hebrew` working?

Comment: I can confirm the strange behavior. On the other hand, `\raggedright` works correctly in normal paragraphs.

Comment: But, isn't it reasonable to expect `\printbiblioraphy` to set its own paragraph alignments? I suggest you consult the biblatex documentation about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you should customize the bibliography layout by modifying `\bibsetup`. However the `bidi` package, loaded by `polyglossia` with RTL languages, redefines `\raggedright`. This new definition has no effect on list items when issued outside the list environment. So the problem you see with `\printbibliography` also applies to `enumerate` and `itemize`.

To cope with this, you can invoke `\raggedright` inside the list environment. For bibliography environments in particular add to your preamble:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\raggedright}
```

Otherwise you can save the original definition of `\raggedright` before loading `polyglossia`.

```
\let\origraggedright\raggedright
\usepackage{polyglossia}
```

The original `\raggedright` can be issued in the document body, before `\printbibliography`:

```
\origraggedright
\printbibliography
```

or in `\bibsetup`:

```
\appto{\bibsetup}{\origraggedright}
```