# Biblatex - prohibit hyphenation for a specific word

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation

I am using a `biblatex-gost` package. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{halanay,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Differential Equations, Their Stability, Time Lags, Oscillations},
    author = {A. Halanay},
    location = {New York--London},
    publisher = {Acad. Press},
    year = {1968},
    pagetotal = {568},
}
\end{filecontents}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-numeric,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\cite{halanay}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It produces

[image]

As you can see, the word `Oscillations` is broken. How do I prohibit hyphenation for this single word? Or is it possible to disable hyphenation for all references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you could add a hyphenation exception for "oscillations" and tell it to never get broken across lines with

```
\hyphenation{oscillations}
```

See also [No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571/35864).

That approach has several disadvantages, though. It prevents hyphenation of the word everywhere - not just in the bibliography, this can lead to undesirable overfull or underfull lines in the normal document text. But even in the bibliography taking away possible hyphenation points makes justification harder. Finally you need to specify these exceptions manually for every word you to stop from breaking, that is simply not viable if you want to avoid hyphenation in general.

If you want to avoid hyphenation in the bibliography completely, I suggest you use a `\raggedright` (left aligned) bibliography. That way there will be no excessive stretching of space if no hyphenation can be found. See [Biblatex raggedright bibliography with polyglossia hebrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88022/35864).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{halanay,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Differential Equations, Their Stability, Time Lags, Oscillations},
    author = {A. Halanay},
    location = {New York--London},
    publisher = {Acad. Press},
    year = {1968},
    pagetotal = {568},
}
\end{filecontents}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-numeric,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\AtBeginBibliography{\raggedright}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\cite{halanay}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ragged right bibliography without hyphenation]

You could also simply disable hyphenation (see for example [temporarily suppress hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91307/35864)) but that would very likely leave you with overfull lines and since you have little possibilities to intervene manually that is not a viable solution.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Unfortunately, neither `\hyphenation` nor `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}` didn't work. Hyphenation was still there.

Comment: @user2513149 Mhhh `\hyphenations` worked for me. I didn't try `sloppypar`, but I would suggest `\raggedright` anyway. If you don't want any hyphenation it is better to go with ragged right text.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway! I will accept this answer since it contains several solutions.